# BASH: Loops through CSV and cURL rows with grep

Tags: bash, macos, curl, grep

I am aiming to loop through a CSV file in bash, i have some code that is semi working. It does not seem to be completing the cURLs as the command instantly finishes and adds to the fail file. It is reading a single column CSV of URLs.

I have researched with no success, looking at GREP success codes etc. This is just being ran locally on MACOS.

```
INPUT=test.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read col1
do
    if curl -L -s "$col1" | grep -q "string"; then
        echo "${col1}" >> one.txt
    else
        echo "${col1}" >> two.txt
    fi
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

I have also tried the following on the IF line:
`if [[ $(curl -L -s "$col1" | grep -q "string") ]]; then`

Thanks

Comment: Would be great to have a part of test.csv

Comment: Let's try to debug it.  Immediately after the `do` add a line `echo $col1` so that you can see if what you get from reading `test.csv` is really what you want.

Comment: echoing col1 gives me the domains on new lines, i have also added leftover as per @PTRK instruction.

Comment: Please modify your question to add the output of your script with few lines of test.csv.

Comment: After removing the -s i get the following error `curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL` so it must be the URL in cURL

Comment: all links include http://example.com/ some have a forward slash and page and alot are https

Comment: it looks like the output is adding a full stop:
```00000000: 6874 7470 733a 2f2f 7368 6177 696d 7072  https://shawimpr
00000010: 6f76 652e 636f 2e75 6b2f 0d              ove.co.uk/.``` using `printf %s "$col1" | xxd`

Answer (score 1):

From the [bash manual](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html)

> One  line  is  read  from the standard input, or from the file
>   descriptor fd supplied as an argument to the -u option, and the first
>   word is assigned to the first name, the second word to the second
>   name, and so on, with **leftover words and their intervening separators
>   assigned to the last name**

since you only provide one name, col1 is not the first column, but the whole line.

Try  `while read col1 leftover` and use @gboffi's comment advice

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with the following:

`col1=${col1%$'\r'}` - to remove the full stops from output.

```
INPUT=test-sites.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read col1 leftover
do
    col1=${col1%$'\r'}
    if curl -L "${col1}" | grep -q "string"; then
        echo "${col1}" >> one.txt
    else
        echo "${col1}" >> two.txt
    fi
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Thank you for your comments

Comment: Those are carriage returns, not "full stops". The proper solution is to not use a Windows editor.